# Getting the average of a database column from matching records in CakePHP 2.9

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Is there a way (beyond completely custom SQL) to find the average of a table column from records that match certain conditions in CakePHP 2.9?

For example, I can find a list of Fields easily by calling the Field model:

```
$fields = $this->Field->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.username' => 'John Doe',
        'Report.created' => '2018-01-01'
    )
);
```

However, what I really want to get is the *average* of `Field.value`, for all records that match.

What I might do normally is to do a raw SQL query;

```
$average = $this->Field->query('
    select avg(f.value) as average from fields f 
      left join users u on (f.user_id = u.id) 
      left join reports r on (f.report_id = r.id) 
      where u.username = "John Doe" and r.created = "2018-01-01"
');
```

However, I don't necessarily know what the condition fields are are, and I would like to use the power of the CakePHP ORM to build the query.

Is there a way to calculate this average from a `Model::find`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069353/cakephp-2-1-avg-function-for-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have followed Cakephp conventions. You can do Average of a field as below.

```
$average = $this->Field->find('all', array(
'fields' => array('AVG(Field.value) as average'),
'conditions' => array('User.username' => 'John Doe', 'Report.created' => '2018-01-01'),
'contain' => array('User', 'Report')
));
```

Hope you will get the idea.

Comment: This works! The issue with @burzum's suggestion is that the other question was about getting an average for each record, but I needed to get an average of *all* records and use the power of the Cake ORM to select which fields got averaged. Thanks!